# How can I change iTunes country of region when having some credit in my account?

Tags: apple-id, accounts

I moved to Canada and I want to change my country of region from USA to Canada, but when I try to change it ( by click on my account in the iTunes Store and going to my Account Page) it showed me this error:
"You have a store credit balance; you must spend your balance before you can change stores"

[image]

I must mention I have redeem 100$ to my account but I don't have any intention to spent it now, what is my option?

Answer (score 4):

You don't have a good option other than trying to gift away the purchases. Perhaps there is a charity cause on the store you can fund and then gift an app or two to make up the difference.

Even large sums can be disposed of with box sets or movie collections that go for between $30 and $130 on iTunes, but this isn't much better than just going shopping for yourself since you need to narrow down cash equivalent into specific app and music sales.

I've never heard of Apple budging on this requirement when someone asks to have it lifted, and unless they had a system for tracking these "refunds" and transfers, it would mess up their accounting for sales / returns in one tax region to shuttle funds from one to another.

You could of course ask billing support for the country in which you purchased the gift card account.

- http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/ww/

Perhaps for amounts more than the price of 5 complete music albums, Apple Support can work some refund out?

Comment: thanks for your answer I think I should call customer service, because I went to the apple store and they told me they can't do anything :) it's really funny how stupid their procedure are.

Comment: Yeah - the retail stores aren't staffed or trained to support cloud issues and using the online support is far more productive since you can get to someone that can work directly with engineering and see the issue through rather than have to juggle your issue with the other customers that can and will walk in while they are working the account issue.

Comment: Same issue i have it here. But the funny thing i have only 0.36$ in my itune card and i cant find any thing to spent it. I need to change my location. Any good suggestions ?

Comment: @Georges Did you ask iTunes store support to cancel or refund your balance? (Of course taking care to explain the nature of why you wish to have this balance zero?)

Comment: @Georges did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed my Country from India to Thailand, as I have moved to Bangkok, Thailand.

When I opened a paid app (e.g. WhatsApp) it said 'buy', then when I clicked on 'buy' it said that this application has already been purchased and you just need to download it again.

I did the download and it's working.

As for the credit card I have not been recharged for last purchases.
Apple has recently updated the feature to make sure if a person moves from one country to another, he/she does not have to purchase the apps again.

Comment: do you have any credit on your apple-id?